# Extra space above OP's name

Tags: bug, design

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34219961/2451726) and found an extra indent above the OP's name.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Extra Indent]

Usually the extra space won't occur, is the indent occurred due to his `hat`?

Browser: Google chrome Version 47.0.2526.80 m

Comment: Clearly this is because of the hat.

Comment: I love hats! I've got one too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the hat. I don't think it's a bug, look:

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Without aligning the text you'll end up hiding the text:

[image]